# Why Is the sender type null when dealing with events

Tags: c#, generics, events

From C# Via CLR:

> Note A lot of people wonder why the
>   event pattern requires the sender
>   parameter to always  be of type Object
>   After all, since the MailManager will
>   be the only type raising an event with
>   a  NewMail EventArgs object, it makes
>   more sense for the callback method to
>   be prototyped like  this:

```
void MethodName(MailManager sender, NewMailEventArgs e);
```

> The pattern requires the sender
>   parameter to be of type Object mostly
>   because of inheritance   What if Mai
>   lManager were used as a base class for
>   SmtpMailManager? In this case, the
>   callback   method should have the
>   sender parameter prototyped as
>   SmtpMailManager instead of  Mail
>   Manager, but this can’t happen because
>   SmtpMai lManager just inherited the
>   NewMai l  event  So the code that was
>   expecting SmtpMail Manager to raise
>   the event must still have to  cast the
>   sender argument to SmtpMailManager  In
>   other words, the cast is still
>   required, so the  sender parameter
>   might as well be typed as Object.
>
> The next reason for typing the sender
>   parameter as Obj ect is just
>   fexibility  It allows the delegate to
>   be used by multiple types that offer
>   an event that passes a NewMail
>   EventArgs object   For example, a
>   PopMai lManager class could use the
>   delegate even if this class were not
>   derived  from Mail Manager

I just simply cannot understand why the sender is an object - Why can it not be generified? so most of the time we do not need to do generic casts

Comment: Please format your text before posting them - the extra spaces in this post and your previous one make them very hard to read (as does this all being posted as code).

Answer (score 7):

Generics did not exist in C# version 1.

Answer (score 3):

Even if generics were implemented around this, you would still have the same problem.  Inside your `MailManager` object, you would call `this.EventName<MailManager>(this, args)`, and so it would only match people who subscribed to that typed event.

Granted, they could rework the entire way that methods and events are looked up by the CLR so that it's very loose.  Then we would have Javascript# instead of C#, though :p